# Is positive definite the difference between a positive definite and a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that is known to be positive definite.

I also have a diagonal matrix $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that:

$$
0<D_{i,i}\leq A_{i,i}
$$

Can I say that

$$
A-D
$$

is positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: consider $A :=\pmatrix{ a&1\\1&a}$ where $a\gt 1$ and $D :=b\mathrm{I}_2$, where $b$ is such that $0\lt  a-b\lt 1$.